# Create TIN with modified resolution with arcpy

Tags: arcpy, 3d-analyst, resolution, tin

I have the polyline feature file `myfeature.shp` from which I create a TIN file:

```
import arcpy
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("3D")
arcpy.CreateTin_3d("mytin","Coordinate Systems\CH1903 LV03.prj", "myfeature.shp Contour softline", "constrained_delaunay")
arcpy.CheckInExtension("3D")
```

How can I affect the resolution? The parameter `cellsize` from `environment` as suggested in [another case](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/288466/blocky-raster-from-tin-how-to-increase-resolution) does not look like the parameter for this as my problem has nothing to do with raster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TIN's don't have the concept of cell size, rasters do. If you want to improve the resolution then you need to increase the point density of your input data that you are building your TIN from.  So in your case you need to increase the density of lines in your contour dataset or add spot heights.

Comment: I actually intend to decrease the resolution. Is there an option to make arcpy decide how to proceed, e.g. to overrun nodes with little change in the vicinity and to keep nodes where big changes occur nearby?

Comment: Not sure, I've never needed to build a TIN, I would start by reading up on what ESRI has to say in their [concepts](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/how-create-tin-3d-analyst-works.htm) section.

Comment: you can try decimate nodes from esri https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/decimate-tin-nodes.htm